# Azure B2C login demo user via API and not through login page

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

How can I login a demo user with azure B2C through a API without using username and password?

I like to give visitors access to a demo account without having to sign up.

Basically my first idea is to provide a azure function or app service which returns a valid user token and/or forwards user to the app with the signed in guest user.

My app uses azure b2c oauth taking the token from url after redirect back to the app, thus it should be easy to provide the token from a second source.

I thought it should be possible to generate a valid user token through a API? Thus the API itself runs under a service user, having the right to generate the token (eg. impersonation).

What's the right approach / B2C APIs to generate this token?

Comment: can't you just create a guest user inside your azure AD?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want users to have to enter username and password.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to access the /authorize or /token endpoint.

Why not just create a dummy user and give people the name and password?

Or a page that kicks off the [resource owner password flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=applications) with canned credentials.

Comment: It may run in demo without keyboard. What are canned credentials and how do I use them.

Comment: They are hard-coded in the resource owner password flow